# Crystal will disappear when previewing a subreport

Tags: crystal-reports

Crystal is proving to be an increasing PITA... anyway, this is my brand new problem :-)

I'm still working on the balance report, with the same structure, except that now the third party assets work beautifully. It has been implemented by using a subreport, but I'm now trying to include it in a new report, because I need to replicate all of the subreports in a new subreport which has different filter conditions.

Since this is quite an undertaking, I thought the best way was to have yet another report which would include the previous ones, hence my tests to make it work.

When I choose "Insert|Subreport..." I can find the file, add it, position it and edit the links. So far, so good. Problem is when I try to preview it, Crystal simply disappears. I'm at loss as to why it's behaving like that and obviously there's no error message being displayed prior to vanishing.
The event viewer doesn't help in this case, no message there either.
A quick skim on google doesn't seem to list anything relevant(yet it's possible I missed it?) .

I have no idea if Crystal Reports has some kind of logging, if it does then it's not clearly visible at a glance.

Would you please point me in the right direction? I'm really clueless.

Thank you for your time,

Andrew

Comment: What do you mean by 'Crystal simply disappears'? The process closes automatically?

Comment: No, it simply vanishes out - I assume it crashes without giving notices.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how I did it, but eventually it worked.
I would still, however, **love** to hear from you about what may have made it go crazy since, again, I have **no clule** as to how I made it avoid crashing, and anyway it's not previewing any data(and I'm sure there are data) so it still kinda doesn't work.

Andrew